# How does JSON.mapping macro work with union types of arguments?

Tags: crystal-lang

In `JSON.mapping` [documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/JSON.html#mapping-macro) explicitly stated the value of `type` property should be single type. However, in practice union types also works:

```
json1 = %q({"ok": true, "result": [{"type": "update", "id": 1}, {"type": "update", "id": 2}]})
json2 = %q({"ok": true, "result": {"type": "message"}})

class Response
  JSON.mapping({
    ok: Bool,
    result: Message | Array(Update)
  })
end

class Update
  JSON.mapping({
    type: String,
    id: Int32
  })
end

class Message
  JSON.mapping({
    type: String
  })
end
```

Calling `Response.from_json` on both JSON string will output expected result.

```
Response.from_json json1
```

will output:

```
#<Response:0x10d20ce20
  @ok=true,
  @result=
  [#<Update:0x10d20cc60 @id=1, @type="update">,
   #<Update:0x10d20cbe0 @id=2, @type="update">]>
```

And

```
Response.from_json json2
```

will output:

```
#<Response:0x10d20c180
  @ok=true,
  @result=#<Message:0x10e241f80 @type="message">>
```

My question is how does it work? Is it expected behaviour or random unreliable feature?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: In that case, how does the macro choose what type to apply on the passing json? Consider following play — https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3b84. `Message` and `Nessage` type are the same, but no matter in what order I specify them in class declaration or in type union, mapper always chooses the `Message`.

Comment: It's in alphabetical order, it seems.